# Possible to query by key instead of value in Hazelcast (using Predicates)?

Tags: java, hazelcast

In Hazelcast, is it possible to query an IMap based on attributes of a key instead of the values?  All the Hazelcast examples show querying by value.  E.g., for a map of employees with keys that are strings:

```
IMap<String, Employee> employees;
```

The typical search predicates then search based on employee attributes (name, salary, etc).  But my case uses more complex keys, such as:

```
IMap<DataAttributes, DataValue> myData;
```

So if DataAttributes has fields such as:

```
 class DataAttributes {
     String theDescription;
     Date   theStartTime;
     public String getDescription() { return theDescription; }
     // etc....
 }
```

I want to write a predicate that can query by the keys, to return an appropriate DataValue object.  This does not work:

```
Predicate pred = Predicates.equal("description", "myDescription");
myData.keySet(pred);  // Throws IllegalArgumentException: "There is no suitable accessor for..."
```

I could roll-my-own as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591381/using-predicate-to-search-a-keyset-in-hazelcast), but I'd rather use an out-of-the-box solution if I can.

It doesn't matter if I wind up using the Criteria API, or the Distributed SQL Query API.  Any working query would be great.  Bonus points for a solution that works on nested attributes (i.e.: DataAttributes `theStartTime.getYear()`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible using PredicateBuilder (`com.hazelcast.query.PredicateBuilder`).  The PredicateBuilder paradigm allows you to query based on keys, like so:

```
EntryObject eo = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
Predicate fredWithStartTimeThisYear = eo.key().get("Description").equal("Fred")
  .and(eo.key().get("theStartTime.Year").equal(2015));
```

Note that you can refer to class members by accessor method ("getter") or field name, as you can see in the above example code.  I found this information in the ["Mastering Hazelcast"](http://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/) online book, available at hazelcast.org (but you have to fill out a registration form to gain access to it).

Comment: note that using predicate (on key or values) is VERY expensive when a lot of data is loaded in the map... be careful with this usage !

Comment: @Donatello Right.  I usually use indexes to mitigate this.  And using an appropriate serializer is also helpful.